# Multiply two matrices

Tags: c#, matrix, console-application, multiplication

I need some help. I have to write a method multiplying two matrices together. Here is my code but I got an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

```
static int[,] FalkScheme(
    int[,] Matrix1,
    int[,] Matrix2,
    int rowcountmatrix1,
    int columncountmatrix1,
    int rowcountmatrix2,
    int columncountmatrix2)
{
    int[,] NewMatrix = new int[rowcountmatrix1, columncountmatrix2];

    if (columncountmatrix1 != rowcountmatrix2)
    {
        throw new Exception("the dimensions of the matrices do not fit! Please try operation with other matrices again!");            
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcountmatrix1; i++)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < columncountmatrix2; u++)
            {
                NewMatrix[i, u] = Matrix1[i, u] * Matrix2[i, u] + Matrix1[i, u + 1] * Matrix2[i + 1, u] + Matrix1[i, u + 2] * Matrix2[i + 2, u];
            }
        }

        return NewMatrix;
    }
}
```

Can you help me fix that problem?

Comment: On which line exactly? Did you debug your code?

Comment: You don't need any of `rowcountmatrix1`..`columncountmatrix2`; just call `Matrix1.GetLength(0);` or `Matrix2.GetLength(1);`

Comment: i+1,u+1,u+2 gets you out of index when you are looping up to rowcountmatrix1 and columncountmatrix2 respectively

Comment: Great! GetLength is really usefull!

Comment: While matrix multiplication is well-known to me, I hadn't heard about this guy [Falk](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falksches_Schema) before. I didn't know the "scheme" had a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any `rowcountmatrix1`..`columncountmatrix2`: ask arrays for its *dimensions*:

```
public static int [,] FalkScheme(int[,] Matrix1, int[,] Matrix2) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Matrix1))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Matrix1");
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, Matrix2))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Matrix2");

  int r1 = Matrix1.GetLength(0);
  int c1 = Matrix1.GetLength(1);

  int r2 = Matrix2.GetLength(0);
  int c2 = Matrix2.GetLength(1);

  if (c1 != r2)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Matrix2", "Matrixes dimensions don't fit.");

  int[,] result = new int[r1, c2];

  // Naive matrix multiplication: O(n**3) 
  // Use Strassen algorithm O(n**2.81) in case of big matrices
  for (int r = 0; r < r1; ++r) 
    for (int c = 0; c < c2; ++c) {
      int s = 0;

      for (int z = 0; z < c1; ++z) 
        s += Matrix1[r, z] * Matrix2[z, c];

      result[r, c] = s;
    }

  return result;
}
```

Test

```
   int[,] a = new int[,] { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
   int[,] b = new int[,] { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } , {9, 10}};
   //  46  52
   // 109 124 
   int[,] c = Problems.FalkScheme(a, b);
```

Comment: I think the result should have the same number of columns as Matrix2. So should be: int[,] result = new int[r1, c2]; More details at: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/properties-of-matrix-multiplication/a/matrix-multiplication-dimensions

Comment: @openshac: quite right, matrix `b` has *two* colums (and three line); the product `c` has *two* columns as well.

Comment: @openshac: Oh, thank you very much for the edit! Definitely, `new int[r1, c2];` since `for (int c = 0; c < c2; ++c)` `// <- c2` I'm sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 0):

In a loop where you count up to a limit with i, or u, and you include code `i+1` or `u+1`, this pushes you beyond the limit - assuming rowcount is the number of rows in your array, say 10, i+1 in the last iteration will be 10, and as arrays are 0 indexed, there is no 10th element, as you have started at 0

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you will get a "Out of range" Exception.

Say the matrixes are 5 rows and 5 columns, e.g. lowest index are 0,0 and highest index 4,4 in both matrixes. In you loop you go from 0,0 to 4,4 so when you are at 4,4 you look for "Matrix2[i, u + 2]" which is 4, 6. Which is higher than 4,4 and therefore the OutOfRangeException.

You need something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowcountmatrix1; i++)
{
    for (int u = 0; u < columncountmatrix2; u++)
    {
        NewMatrix[i, u] = 0; // The position in the new Matrix we need to calculate

        for (int x = 0; x < rowcountmatrix2 /* same as columncountmatrix1 */; x++)
        {
            NewMatrix[i, u] += Matrix1[i, x] * Matrix2[x, u];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in the `if` block makes no sense? The code in your `else` block looks like what is needed in all cases (sum over `x`).

Comment: Read this for matrix multiplication: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

If the dimension is squared e.g. 2,2 in both matrixes then result[0,0] is m1[0,0] * m2[0,0] * 2. NOT m1[0,0] * m2[0,0] + m[0,1] * m[1,0].

Comment: Trim your answer into `for (int i = 0; i < rowcountmatrix1; i++)
{
    for (int u = 0; u < columncountmatrix2; u++)
    {
            NewMatrix[i, u] = 0; // The position in the new Matrix we need to calculate

            for (int x = 0; x < rowcountmatrix2 /* same as columncountmatrix1 */; x++)
            {
                NewMatrix[i, u] += Matrix1[i, x] * Matrix2[x, u];
            }
    }
}` and it will be correct.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Have you read the information in the link I posted?

Comment: That link says correctly: _To multiply an `m×n` matrix by an `n×p` matrix, the `n`s must be the same, 
 and the result is an `m×p` matrix._ But you seem to introduce a special case when `m == n`, i.e. when the left factor `Matrix1` is square. But there is nothing special about that case. You still have to let `x` run through all the values up to `n` (`n` is the common "dimension" of the two matrices).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I wasn't thinking clearly. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Matrix1[i, u] * Matrix2[i, u] + Matrix1[i, u + 1] * Matrix2[i + 1, u] + Matrix1[i, u + 2] * Matrix2[i + 2, u]
```

(three terms). Is your method meant to only multiply matrices of size `m×3` and `3×n` respectively? Otherwiser, change this sum of *three* terms into a sum of `columncountmatrix1` (`== rowcountmatrix2`) terms.

Consider something like

```
Enumerable.Range(0, columncountmatrix1).Sum(x => Matrix1[i, x] * Matrix2[x, u]);
```

As others have said, the sizes of the two matrices are built into the array objects, so your method should not take them in as separate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need three for loops
try the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) 
    {
        C[i,j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
        {
            C[i,j] += A[i,k] * B[k,j];
        }
    }
}
```